# Setting up Preferred Search Center for My Sites defaulting to default public URL

Tags: search, my-site, url

I'm having a problem correctly linking the My Site preferred search center to our main portal application's search center.

In the User Profile service, Setup My Sites link, there is a place to specify the preferred search center.  No matter what you put into this field, it will automatically change to whatever the public URL is of the default zone for the web application of the search center you are trying to link it to.  However, for our purposes, we need to use the search center with the Internet zone public URL, not the default zone public URL.

Here is my current AAM setup for the main portal web application:

```
Zone    | Internal URL | Public URL | Comments

Default | sptestapp01.adtest.company.com:443 | sptestapp01.adtest.company.com:443

Internet | insideisatest.company.com:443 | insideisatest.company.com:443

Internet | sptestweb01.adtest.company.com:443 | insideisatest.company.com:443 | This is web front end #1

Internet | sptestweb02.adtest.company.com:443 | insideisatest.company.com:443 | This is web front end #2
```

Here is the current AAM setup for the My Sites web application:

```
Zone    | Internal URL | Public URL | Comments

Default | mytest.company.com:443 | mytest.company.com:443

Default | mytest.company.com:447 | mytest.company.com:443

Default | sptestweb01.adtest.company.com:447 | mytest.company.com:443 | This 
is web front end #1

Default | sptestweb02.adtest.company.com:447 | mytest.company.com:443 | This is web front end #2
```

We reverse proxy everything through an ISA/TMG server, so the public access URL to the main portal is `insideisatest.company.com` and the public access URL to My Sites is `mytest.company.com`.

So right now, the preferred search center for My Sites is forced to be `sptestapp01.adtest.company.com/searchcenter/pages`, but we need it to be `insideisatest.company.com/searchcenter/pages`.

Does anyone know how we can do this?  We can’t change the default public zone (`sptestapp01.adtest.company.com`), but cause that is needed for proper search results as well as keeping contextual search working.

Comment: What version are we talking about? 2013? Have you tried setting the URL through PowerShell, just to make sure it's not that: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/10/29/how-to-configure-the-global-search-center-url-for-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell.aspx